# Javascript problem with object cloning and eval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, socket.io, eval

I'm programming a little game with socketio and nodejs server and that is quite new for me. When someone creates a game it sends to the server the info and the server creates an object with all the game info. I'm using the eval() to make the object named after the game-name like "bob_game = {...}".
Here is my code :

```
games.push("Partie de " + data.pseudo);
gamesStatus.push("lobby");
eval("var " + data.pseudo + "_game = {name :'" + data.pseudo + "',status : 2,playerNb : 1,maxPlayerNb :" + data.nbPlayers + ",players : ['" + data.pseudo + "'], xCoords : [], yCoords : [], directions : []}");
io.emit(data.pseudo, {command : "joinGame", game : data.pseudo});
io.emit("updateGameList", {command : "updateGameList", game : games, gameStatus : gamesStatus});
```

This all works correctly and i'm able to send back all the info to other users saying a game has been created !
On the website their is a button for every joinable game. When you press one of them, it sends to the server a joinGameRequest with game id and the player's name. All the info is collected correctly and i'm able to set a temporary object replacing the bob_game object :

```
game = eval(gameName + "_game");
```

This avoids me calling the original object, bob_game, when I want to make a change otherwise I would put eval() everywhere cause bob isn't always called bob...
But, I know that after all the changes made to "game", I have to transfer all the propeties back to bob_game "to save everything in a way". That is where I'm having a problem ... I says game is not defined ... Even though i've been making changes few lines above and I'm able to log the playerNb of game ... So game is defined ...

```
console.log(game.playerNb);
eval(gameName + "_game = game");
```

I need help pls xD

Comment: You should also get comfortable with setting breakpoints in your code, so you can inspect exactly what's going on. Chrome Developer Tools is your friend

Comment: Or add `debugger` inline within your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't do this:

```
eval("var " + data.pseudo + "_game = {
```

If you need to have something called 'bob_game', put it inside of an object

```
var games = {};
var newGameKey = data.pseudo + "_game";
games[newGameKey] = {...};
```

Then you can always access it by that key.

Comment: Also, don't create objects with eval. If they come in the form of strings, use `JSON.parse(string)`, otherwise, create them in regular javascript `myObject = {name: data.pseudo, ...}`

Comment: so is then games an array or an object ? or both ? can it be like this ?
games[bob_game] = {playerNb = 1}
games[mike_game] = {playerNb = 3}

Comment: It is an object, not an array. I hope this jsfiddle helps you: https://jsfiddle.net/zpkL5vw4/

Comment: how would i get all the name propety of all games ? like a array = game[all].name

Comment: `var listOfGames = Object.keys(games);` -- this is actually one of the important reasons why you'd want it in an object like that. It's very easy to view what's available, programatically and visually.

Comment: Ok last question : how would I delete a key of games like bob_game doesn't exist anymore ?

Comment: to delete a key from an object, `var key = 'bob_game'; delete obj[key]`